# Checkbox inside of form label tag

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how I can put the checkbox inside the label tag like my template has it with the form helper with codeigniter.

```
echo "<div class=\"actions-left\" style=\"margin-top: 8px;\">";
echo form_label('Auto-login in future.', 'autologin');
echo form_checkbox('autologin');
echo "</div>";
```

[Login Page](http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/)

[Login Template](http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/peach/Template/login.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I don't know CodeIgniter, but would this work:

`echo form_label( form_checkbox( 'autologin' ) . ' Auto-login in future' );`

Comment: @apis [form_helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) see form_label(). All it does it output html based on passed parameters. same as form_checkbox() which is being passed as the "text" in the example above.

Comment: Its very strange. There is nothing like this in CodeIgniter Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to check now, but is it valid markup? anyway, you can use the "regular" html for the `<label>` tag:

```
<div class="actions-left" style="margin-top: 8px">
<label for="autologin">Auto-login in future <?php echo form_checkbox('autologin'); ?>
</label>
</div>
```

Or you could try using the return value of form_checkbox() as the 1st argument of form_label(), i.e. it's content:

```
echo "<div class=\"actions-left\" style=\"margin-top: 8px;\">";
echo form_label(form_checkbox('autologin'), 'autologin');
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: it's usually done because we want the checkbox to be toggled even when the user clicks the label... so they don't need to hunt the tiny 2px-sq. box that's the checkbox with their mouse...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know HTML, CSS standarts well but this seems a little bit wierd to me. I mean, "checkbox in a label"

I think you should solve this issue with css.
Please, check this out http://alexking.org/blog/2005/07/18/css-checkbox-label-positioning

Perhaps, i may be wrong here so i do not want to push my idea too much.

Best Regards